# How Are The StackExchange Tiles Layout Generated Programmatically

Tags: html, user-interface, stack, user-experience, information-architecture

On the homepage of StackExchange there is a really well organised set of tiles that shows a huge amount of information in a neatly laid out structure for all of the sites under the stack umbrella.

How was this created programmatically?

[image: stack exchange tiles]

Comment: By an occult group of witches that sang an enchanted song on a night with a blood moon, while a pack of grey wolves was howling and little children were hiding under their beds frightened to death. But seriously this question really belongs on meta.

Comment: Sorry for posting it in the wrong place.  How would I get it moved there?

Comment: Don't really see why this would be a meta question. He wants to know how this was coded and he's using SE as an example. If he used any other sort of "tag cloud" as an example it wouldn't be a meta question.

Comment: No problemo, just `edit` the question. `copy` the content from the question to your memory. Go to meta and repost. there. Then come back and delete this one.

Comment: @Brandon, well it's specific about `stackexchange` example. On `meta` there are site programmers that could shed some light on the way it's build. And if he used "*other sort of "tag cloud"*" this post will also be closed down.

Comment: @Mouser just to clarify - should I re-post it on Meta under StackExchange or under StackOverflow?  I'm slightly confused which is the correct place for it.

Comment: @motionpotion. Not quite sure myself. Since it's about programming one could say stackOverflow, but the functionality comes from stackExchange. I'd say SO.